# Is it possible to add new files to mercurial commit via pretxncommit hook or any other method?

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-hook

I want to check what files have been modified in current commit and base on that I want to modify or not specified file and add it to that commit.

I was thinking about using script on pretxncommit hook who gives me information that I need but I don't see any possible way to add new modified file to that commit.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: I suppose, you selected The Bad Way(tm) of solving task by fooling commits. Use controlling hooks, block incomplete changesets, add needed files by hand - it's safer

Answer (score 0):

it would not be at `pretxncommit` because at that point the changeset is already built

you'd need to hook earlier, likely on `precommit`

> **precommit**: Controlling. This is run **before** starting a commit.
>
> **pretxncommit**: Controlling. This is run **after** a new changeset has been created in the local repository, but before the transaction that will make it permanent completes.

https://book.mercurial-scm.org/read/hook.html

Comment: You can't use `precommit` hook for this task, just because "It is run before Mercurial has any of the metadata for the commit, such as the files to be committed, the commit message, or the commit date"/ BTW,  `pretxncommit` is also out of game: "This hook can access the metadata associated with the almost-new changeset, but it should not do anything permanent with this data"

Comment: I thought you could combine `hg diff` with `hg status` to figure it out (at `precommit` time), then take the desired action upon it